# Fixed number of widget display on the screen

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, widget

Everyone I am try to develop a UI in which I have a list of category each category has some options.[image]

The issue is pretty silly but not able find a correct solution for it when I expand a particular widget. the count of widget is changing which is on the left side and number widget is increased on the right side I want to fixed number widgets as shown on document is loaded. Example when widget expands is below[image]

My code is like this given below

```
<div class="widget-body  col-lg-12 no-padding">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" ng-repeat="cat in category track by $index"  >
        <section class="widget " data-widgster-collapsed="true" style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:15px; "> 
            <header class="ui-sortable-handle" style=" border-top: 3px solid orange;">
                <h5>
                    <span class="fw-semi-bold">{{cat.Name}}</span>
                    <div class="widget-controls" >
                        <a data-widgster="expand" title="" ng-click="show(cat.Id)" href="#" style="display: none;" data-original-title="Expand">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                        </a> 
                        <a ng-click="hide(cat.Id)"  data-widgster="collapse" title="" href="#" data-original-title="Collapse">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
                        </a> 
                    </div>
                </h5>
            </header>
            <div class="widget-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 checkbox" ng-repeat="opt in cat.option">
                            <input id="{{cat.Id}}_{{opt.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{opt.value}}" ng-model="opt.value"> 
                            <label for="{{cat.Id}}_{{opt.id}}">{{opt.name}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, on expand I want 5 widgets on left and 5 on right and there position must be fixed.

Comment: you are using the angular?

Comment: yes I am using angularjs